# Problems with writing to file Java

Tags: java

I have problems with writing to file. As long as i have not using Math.round(), i have only problem with stopping writing to file after 50~~ rows inserted into file, now i have problem that printWriter write totally nothing to file...

Code:
this is a function that create each line (row)

```
public void addRow (Run run, int index)
    {
        line[this.index+index]=index+" ";
        line[this.index+index]+=run.percentOfCStates+" ";
        line[this.index+index]+=run.avarageIncome+" ";
        line[this.index+index]+=run.percentOfCACell+" ";
        line[this.index+index]+=run.percentOfLACell+" ";
        line[this.index+index]+=run.percentOfCStatesInCACell+" ";
        line[this.index+index]+=run.percentOfCStatesInLACell+" ";
        line[this.index+index]+=run.percentOfSharingCell+" ";
        line[this.index+index]+=run.percentOfAllCStrategy+" ";
        line[this.index+index]+=run.percentOfPcStrategy+" ";
        line[this.index+index]+=run.percentOfallDStrategy+" ";
        line[this.index+index]+=run.percentOfkDStrategy+" ";
        line[this.index+index]+=run.avarageHParameter+" ";
        line[this.index+index]+="0.00";
        if(((int)run.avarageEpsParameter)<100)
            line[this.index+index]+="0";
        line[this.index+index]+=Integer.toString((int)run.avarageEpsParameter)+" ";
        line[this.index+index]+=run.avaragePcParameter+" ";
        for (int i=0; i <run.percentOfkD.length-1;i++)
            line[this.index+index]+=run.percentOfkD[i]+" ";
        line[this.index+index]+=run.percentOfkD[7];
        System.out.println(line[this.index+index]);
    }
```

this is my function that write to file

```
public void writeToFile(String pathToFile) throws FileNotFoundException
        {
            out= new PrintWriter(pathToFile);
            for (int i=0; i<line.length; i++)
                out.println(line[i]);
        }
```

this is my function that using Math.round, when i havent used it, it insert something like 50 rows and data was cutted in some point and rest of rows was skipped:

```
    public double   percentOfCStates=0;

    public double   avarageIncome=0;

    public double           CounterOfLACell=0;
    public double       CounterOfCACell=0;
    public double       counterOfPcCell=0;

    public double       percentOfCACell=0;
    public double       percentOfLACell=0;

    public double       percentOfCStatesInCACell=0;
    public double       percentOfCStatesInLACell=0;

    public double       percentOfSharingCell=0;
    public double       percentOfAllCStrategy=0;
    public double       percentOfPcStrategy=0;
    public double       percentOfallDStrategy=0;
    public double       percentOfkDStrategy=0;


    public double       avarageHParameter=0;
    public double       avarageEpsParameter=0;
    public double       avaragePcParameter=0;

    public double       []percentOfkD=new double[8];
public void countStatistics()
        {
            int allCells=this.xRange*this.yRange;

            this.percentOfCStates=Math.round((this.percentOfCStates/allCells)*100);
            this.percentOfCStates/=100;
            this.avarageIncome=(Math.round((this.avarageIncome/(this.CounterOfCACell+this.CounterOfLACell))*100))/10;
            this.avarageIncome/=100;
            this.percentOfCACell=(Math.round((this.percentOfCACell/allCells)*100));
            this.percentOfCACell/=100;
            this.percentOfLACell=(Math.round((this.percentOfLACell/allCells)*100));
            this.percentOfLACell/=100;
            this.percentOfCStatesInCACell=(Math.round((this.percentOfCStatesInCACell/allCells)*100));
            this.percentOfCStatesInCACell/=100;
            this.percentOfCStatesInLACell=(Math.round((this.percentOfCStatesInLACell/allCells)*100));
            this.percentOfCStatesInLACell/=100;
            this.percentOfSharingCell=(Math.round((this.percentOfSharingCell/allCells)*100));
            this.percentOfSharingCell/=100;
            this.percentOfAllCStrategy=(Math.round((this.percentOfAllCStrategy/allCells)*100));
            this.percentOfAllCStrategy/=100;
            this.percentOfPcStrategy=(Math.round((this.percentOfPcStrategy/allCells)*100));
            this.percentOfPcStrategy/=100;
            this.percentOfallDStrategy=(Math.round((this.percentOfallDStrategy/allCells)*100));
            this.percentOfallDStrategy/=100;
            this.percentOfkDStrategy=(Math.round((this.percentOfkDStrategy/allCells)*100));
            this.percentOfkDStrategy/=100;
            this.avarageHParameter=(Math.round((this.avarageHParameter/this.CounterOfLACell)*100));
            this.avarageHParameter/=100;
            this.avarageEpsParameter=(Math.round((this.avarageEpsParameter/this.CounterOfLACell)));
            //this.avarageEpsParameter/=100;
            this.avaragePcParameter=(Math.round(this.avaragePcParameter/this.counterOfPcCell)*100);
            this.avaragePcParameter/=100;
            for(int i=0; i<this.percentOfkD.length; i++)
            {
                this.percentOfkD[i]=(Math.round((this.percentOfkD[i]/allCells)*100));
                this.percentOfkD[i]/=100;
            }
        }
```

have you got any suggestions?

## edit

object statistics have that writeToFile function inside.

```
try {
    statistics.writeToFile("text.txt");
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("Error");
}
```

## edit2

```
0 0.42 0.38 0.35 0.35 0.21 0.21 0.35 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.08 8.0 0.00100 1.0 0.04 0.04 0.04 0.04 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
1 0.41 0.34 0.21 0.49 0.13 0.29 0.28 0.01 0.03 0.1 0.06 8.0 0.00100 0.0 0.04 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
2 0.42 0.36 0.14 0.56 0.09 0.33 0.26 0.01 0.02 0.07 0.05 8.0 0.00100 0.0 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.06 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
3 0.42 0.37 0.1 0.59 0.07 0.35 0.26 0.0 0.01 0.04 0.04 8.0 0.00100 0.0 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.06 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, is any of this surrounded by a `try...catch` where you ignore exceptions?

Comment: Also, are you sure `allCells` is not `0`?

Comment: Math.round absolutely is not your problem, but as others have indicated, you could be throwing exceptions. I would wrap your entire main inside a try-catch, where the catch dumps the exception. This will catch any exceptions you're not otherwise trapping. And your addRow method is quite confusing, but that's probably a different matter.

Comment: I edited post, first thing is that i try to catch exceptions. Second thing is that i have that System.out.println() at end of addRow() function, and i have all rows that i wanted to have, in file i don't have any of those.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca i throw simple if (allCells==0) syso("ASFASDJF"); and havent got msg, so its not the reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to close your printwriter.

Since writing to disk is slow, but writing to memory is fast, printwriter (and other parts of the pipeline) keep buffers containing pending data.

These buffers are only flushed when you call either `close` or `flush`, letting the the reference expire does not flush them

The easiest solution now is using a "try-with-resources" statement, that handles this for you in all cases.

```
try(PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter(pathToFile)) {
    // Use p to write things
}
```

This will also handle closing the writer in the case of any unhandled exceptions